# Applying Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Apply the Cauchy–Goursat theorem to show that $\int_{C}^{}f(z)dz=0$ when the contour C is the unit circle $\left | z \right |=1$ , in either direction, and when $f(z)=sechz$.

here is solution: Note that f is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left \{ \frac{(2n+1)\pi }{2} \right \}$. Since $\frac{\pi }{2}>1=\left | z \right |$ , none of $\left \{ \frac{(2n+1)\pi }{2} \right \}$ lie in the region bounded by the contour  $C$ which implies that $f$ is analytic on the region bounded by $C$ as well as on contour $C$. Therefore , by Cauchy-Goursat theorem,we have $$\int_{C}^{}sechz dz=0$$

Is it true that the given function analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left \{ \frac{(2n+1)\pi }{2} \right \}$? I am not sure about this solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ${\rm sech}z$ is not analytic at $z=0$ which is inside the bounded part of your curve

Comment: @janmarqz ??? You must be confusing sech with csch or something...

Comment: Yes, it's true that $f$ is analytic on that set. You should probably explain why this is so...

Comment: Ha!, maybe I am sleepy

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks